# Why the connection speed is limited to 20-30 mbit/s in the case of a PPP daemon?

Tags: modem, ppp, lte, huawei

I'm configuring my LTE modem (Huawei E3372s-153, NON-HiLink), and I recently found out that this modem can work in two different modes: RAS and NDIS (NCM). The second one works just as normal NIC and allows to reach the full speed of the device. In the case of RAS, which is just a PPP daemon, the connection speed is limited to 20-30 mbit/s, at least that's what I've head. I couldn't even reach the speed, so I don't really know what's the truth. So I have a question concerning the modem speed in the RAS mode -- is the speed really that low in this mode? If so, what's the cause? Why the PPP daemon limits the connection speed of the modem?